# MDI Child Forms Opening each other with the same parent form

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

So I have 3 Forms, lets call them Form1, Form2, and Form3.
I have sent the IsMDIParent Property to true for Form1.

When I launch the app, It loads Form2 as an MDI Child using

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();
```

And that works fine. What I then want to do is click a button withing the 2nd form that will close Form2 and open up Form3 as a child form of Form1.

I tried

```
SecondForm SecondFormMDI = new SecondForm();
SecondFormMDI.MdiParent = Form1;
SecondFormMDI.Show();
```

on the button click event in Form2, but it would not work.

Do I have to always launch a Child form from the parent form? and if so, how would i go about doing that when it is on the button click event on a child form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this.MdiParent, instead of Form1, like

```
    SecondForm SecondFormMDI = new SecondForm();
    SecondFormMDI.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    SecondFormMDI.Show();
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't know I could do this (stupid lecturer)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MDIParent of any form in design time, why do it in run-time?
Simply set the value of MDIParent property of Form2 and Form3 to Form1, and that's it.

Comment: Looking in the Properties box for the form, I cannot see 'MDIParent' listed there?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, I thought I remember it correctly, turns out I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in your MDIForm to open a childform:

```
public void OpenForm(Form form)
{
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}
```

When you want to open a new form in another form you do something like this (example in ChildFormOne with button):

```
private void btnOpenChildFormTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MDIForm)this.MdiParent).OpenForm(new ChildFormTwo());
    this.Close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChildForm frmChild = new ChildForm();
frmChild.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
frmChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill();
frmChild.Show();
```